# Pandas how to shift na values to the right?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a dataframe like

```
|x |y |z |
|na|na|1 |
|na|2 |1 |
|2 |3 |1 |
|na|na|1 |
```

and I want to shift the NA values so the NA elements will move to the last keeping the order of the non-na values columns like

```
|x |y |z |
|1 |na|na|
|2 |1 |na|
|2 |3 |1 |
|1 |na|na|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try

```
df=df.replace('na',np.nan).transform(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull),1)
   x    y    z
0  1  NaN  NaN
1  2    1  NaN
2  2    3    1
3  1  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: This is nice. Should be replicable within the ```sort``` function in the 1.1 version