# Python / Pandas: Shift entities of a row to the right (end)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, shift

I have the following data frame (number of "Date" columns can vary):

**Customer  Date1  Date2  Date3  Date4**
0        A     10   40.0    NaN   60.0

1        B     20   50.0    NaN    NaN

2        C     30    NaN    NaN    NaN

If there is a "NaN" in the last column (as said, number of columns can vary), I want to right shift all the columns to the end of the data frame such that it then looks like this:

**Customer  Date1  Date2  Date3  Date4**

0        A     10   40.0    NaN   60.0

1        B    NaN    NaN     20   50.0

2        C    NaN    NaN    NaN     30

All the values which remain empty can be set to NaN.

How can I do that in Python?

I tried this code but didn't work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Customer': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Date1': [10, 20, 30],
    'Date2': [40, 50, np.nan],
    'Date3': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'Date4': [60, np.nan, np.nan]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


for i in range(1, len(df.columns)):
    df.iloc[:, i] = df.iloc[:, i-1].shift(fill_value=np.nan)

print(df)
```

Comment: What should be the result if Date1 is 10, Date2 is NaN, Date3 is 20 and Date4 is NaN? `NaN NaN 10 20` or `NaN 10 NaN 20` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily set the non-target columns as index (or drop them), then push the non-NaNs to the right with sorting, and only update the rows that are matching a specific mask (here NaN in the last column):

```
out = (df
   .set_index('Customer', append=True)
   .pipe(lambda d: d.mask(d.iloc[:, -1].isna(),
                          d.transform(lambda x : sorted(x, key=pd.notnull), axis=1)
                         )
        )
   .reset_index('Customer')
)
```

Alternative:

```
other_cols = ['Customer']
out = df.drop(columns=other_cols)
m = out.iloc[:, -1].isna()
out.loc[m, :] = out.loc[m, :].transform(lambda x : sorted(x, key=pd.notnull), axis=1)
out = df[other_cols].join(out)[df.columns]
```

*NB. there are several methods to shift non-NaNs, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62399659/16343464) is one, but non-sorting based methods are possible if this is a bottleneck.*

Output:

```
  Customer  Date1  Date2  Date3  Date4
0        A   10.0   40.0    NaN   60.0
1        B    NaN    NaN   20.0   50.0
2        C    NaN    NaN    NaN   30.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a row with only NaN values, you could use:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    while(np.isnan(df.iloc[i,-1])):
        df.iloc[i,1:]=df.iloc[i,1:].shift(periods=1, fill_value=np.nan)
```

Output:

[image]