# Shift entities of a row to the right based on filtering?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

if found a great solution from @mozway to shift entities to the right of a column here:

[Python / Pandas: Shift entities of a row to the right (end)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76704112/python-pandas-shift-entities-of-a-row-to-the-right-end)

If there is a NaN in the last column (number of columns can vary), I want to right shift all the columns to the end of the data frame such that it then looks like below:

The solution works fine:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Customer': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Date1': [10, 20, 30],
    'Date2': [40, 50, np.nan],
    'Date3': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'Date4': [60, np.nan, np.nan]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

out = (df
   .set_index('Customer', append=True)
   .pipe(lambda d: d.mask(d.iloc[:, -1].isna(),
                          d.transform(lambda x : sorted(x, key=pd.notnull), axis=1)
                         )
        )
   .reset_index('Customer')
)
```

But is there a way with the existing solution to implement a filter, that only the rows are shifted, which contain e.g. the word main in Customer? It shall look like this: Cucumber.main was shifted, because of main in the word. Strawberry.fruit not, because main is missing.

Desired Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new condition to [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
out = (df
   .set_index('Customer', append=True)
   .pipe(lambda d: d.mask(d.iloc[:, -1].isna() &
                          df['Customer'].str.contains('main').to_numpy(),
                          d.transform(lambda x : sorted(x, key=pd.notnull), axis=1)
                         )
        )
   .reset_index('Customer')
)
```

Or use level of `MultiIndex` by [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
out = (df
   .set_index('Customer', append=True)
   .pipe(lambda d: d.mask(d.iloc[:, -1].isna() & 
                          d.index.get_level_values('Customer').str.contains('main'),
                          d.transform(lambda x : sorted(x, key=pd.notnull), axis=1)
                         )
        )
   .reset_index('Customer')
)
```